# How to create a photo attachment for an issue with Autodesk Forge API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to attach a photo via the Forge API to an issue like it does in BIM 360 when drag and drop files into the Attachments tab.

I tried to create a bucket, upload a file there and attach the uploaded file with "urnType" = "oss" using a POST request for attachments. But it crashes with 403 code at attacment post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to follow this tutorial : [Attach BIM360 Files](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/issues/attach-BIM-360-files/)

<s>The `urnType` should be `"dm"` in the POST request</s>

**EDIT :**

If you want to upload pictures and be able to see it, you can use `"oss"` for the `urnType` but instead of using the urn of the picture from `folderContents` endpoint ex : `urn:adsk.wip:dm.lineage:...` use the `objectId` in the response of the upload ex : `urn:adsk.objects:os.object:wip.dm.prod/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xx.png`

Then if you check the attachment details you'll get `attachment-type:"photo"` instead of `"document"` and be able to see the thumbnail in the issue details.

I tried it and it worked for me (and you have one step less in the process of adding pictures attachment )

Comment: I am currently using this variant. It is not suitable as the files will not appear in the "Photos" section. Also, I would like the files to be as hidden as when dragging and dropping files into BIM 360.

Comment: I edited my answer with a way to get the "photo" attachment type. However I don't know how to hide files on BIM360. Maybe we can add a "hidden" property but I never tested it.

Comment: It really helps. If do not create a version, then it seems like the file cannot be found in Ducument Management. So maybe this will be my solution of the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, you still need to create the file version. For the hidden folder, you can `PATCH` your picture folder using this endpoint : https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-folders-folder_id-PATCH/. You need to add the `attribute -> "hidden" : true`